# Load PHP File Using Ajax (Without JQUery)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, apache

I have the following Ajax code in an html file:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js">
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url:"nba2019_namelist.php",
        success:function(res) {
            $("#playerNames").html(res)
        }
    })
</script>
```

This is supposed to load a php file (which really just creates a list from a csv), but is not working. I am using Apache to make php function, and when I go to http:/localhost/nba2019_namelist.php, my list is present, so I am fairly certain that the php file isn't the issue. The ajax code is meant to replace the following html list:

```
<div>
  <ul id="playerNames">
      <li><b>Harden</b></li>
      <li><b>Giannis</b></li>
      <li><b>Lebron</b></li>
      <li><b>Booker</b></li>
      <li><b>Lavine</b></li>
      <li><b>Westbrook</b></li>
      <li><b>Jokic</b></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But the only output when I load the page are the same names that are typed in here, not the ones created by my php file. What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to specify in the Apache httpd.conf which php file I want to load? I don't really know any Ajax, but based on what I have seen on forums, it should work. What am I doing wrong here, and what should I do next to fix this issue?

If JQuery is the only solution, just let me know, I would just rather not learn something new at the moment, unless it is completely necessary.

Comment: jQuery isn't the only solution for making AJAX requests, no. There's XmlHttpRequest and fetch() which are both native built-in AJAX libraries available in every modern browser by default, and there are other ones out there too, similar to the jQuery version. The key thing you haven't done here, as far as I can tell, is debug your code. Did you open your browser's Developer Tools and check the Console and Network tools to look for errors and problems with the AJAX call? That's the first basic step you need to take.

Comment: CHeck your console, `method: GET` should be `method: "GET",`

Comment: P.S. from a glance at the code, I'd suspect `method: GET` might be a problem - it could be causing a syntax error, or at least `GET` is probably undefined. It's supposed to be a string. Change it to `method: "GET",`  - you also forgot the comma at the end before the next option - that definitely _will_ cause a syntax error. This is a basic, basic error which you would have caught immediately if you'd looked at your Console. You can't learn to program unless you also learn how to debug your programs at the same time. Take the time to work that out, and you'll save hours of frustration later.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! Unfortunately, after switching the code to `method: "GET",`, the same result happens. Thanks for the tip on using the console to debug, my current editor doesn't have a debug tool, so I'll be sure to find a new one that does.

Comment: For Javascript, it's the browser which does the debugging, not the code editor (although the editor could highlight syntax errors for you before you try and run the code)

Comment: "the same result happens"...and what result is that, specifically? Again, open the Developer Tools, and then load your page, to get clues about what problems happen. You want to be looking for console errors, and then look in the Network tool to see if the request to nba2019_namelist.php actually happens, does it appear in the list of requests? If the request does happen, then do you get a "200" (OK) response code? And when you click on the AJAX request to nba2019_namelist.php from the Network tool, and go to the Response tab within it, what do you see there? Is it what you expected?

Comment: P.S. for clarity, the Developer Tools I am referring to are located within your browser. Press F12 in most browsers to open them. Personally I think the Chrome ones are the best / easiest to use (and I'd avoid Internet Explorer's), but all of them are fine for this task, and look and feel similar enough that my description of what to do should broadly fit them all.

Comment: Sorry, by "the same result happens", I meant that the small list that I initially had is still displayed, but the list created by php is not shown. Thanks for helping me find the console - there were three errors, I was able to fix all of them by disabling chrome extensions and then adding to the script tag 'type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js"'. Now there are 0 errors on the console, but the list created by php still isn't shown. Any ideas as to what else the issue with my code could be? I'd be glad to share relevant pieces of the code.

Comment: Like I said above, once you've checked the Console (and got rid of the errors), now you need to check the Network tool to see if there's a problem with the request. There is, on the face of it, not a lot wrong with your jQuery code, but there could be a subtle issue which we can narrow things down to, with a bit more debugging information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix my own problem. I followed a tutorial online that suggested changing my vanilla  `<script>` tag that contained my ajax code to instead read `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js">`. This made my code not function properly.

To solve this, I changed my script tag back to the vanilla `<script>`, and instead put the following at the bottom of my `<head>`: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>`

This allowed my php code to be grabbed from ajax as expected.

Comment: yes that's the standard way to include an external Javascript library into your page. You always need to do that before you can use a library such as jQuery. Glad you fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Learned a lot about dev tools which will be very helpful moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Try this by using fetch:

```
fetch('nba2019_namelist.php')
.then(response=>response.Text())
.then(data => { 
     document.getElementById("playerNames").innerHTML = data;
 });
```

I hope it helps